# How to call struts2 action from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, struts2, multi-select

I work with Struts2 , Hibernate3 and jpa 
I have 3 tables:

```
1 Evaluationglobale (id_eval ,label)
2 SousEval(id_eval ,id_sousitem),
3 SousItems(id_sousitem ,label)
```

How do I add a record into SousEval? i  want to use the last insert ID in table Evaluationglobale for insert meny record into SousEval that i recupere this record from SousItems

I have  that

```
   id_eval       label
    ----------------------------
    1              evaluation 1


    id_sousitem     SousItem_Libelle
    ----------------------------
    1              sousitem 1
    2              sousitem 2
    3              sousitem 3
    4              sousitem 4

i want insert somthing like that  

    id_eval       id_sousitem
    ----------------------------
    1              1
    1              2
    1              3
    1              4
```

And  I don't know how to recuper all id_sousitem  from iterator from this jsp :
In one of my pages jsp I use an iterator of `<s:select>`that run through table `SousItems` and I have thought to use the event  onchange for each `<s:select>` to call a specific method in my Action bean:
 this some code of my jsp

```
<form action="saveOrupdateSousEval" method="post">
    -----------------some code ------
    <TABLE  class="EvalTable" >
      <s:iterator value="item"  status="userStatus">
         <s:select  label="%{Item_Libelle}"
            headerValue="---------------- Select ---------------"
            headerKey="-1" 
            name="sousEvalItem.SousItem_ID"  
            list="sousitem"
            listKey="sousitem.SousItem_ID"  
            listValue="SousItem_Libelle"
            cssClass="tdLabelwidht"
            value="%{SousItem_ID}"  
            id="EvalTable"
         />
    </s:iterator>
    </TABLE>
    <s:texfield type=hidden value="%{id_eval}" name="id_eval" />       
</form>
```

If I call this event, it should insert the values into my database.
I try do this for simple example it work  but when  i use `<s:select>` of the iterator did't work

```
<s:select  label="Select test"
     headerValue="---------------- Select ---------------"
    headerKey="-1" 
    name="sousEvalItem.SousItem_ID"  
    list="#{'1':'list1','2':'list2','3':'list3'}"
    listKey="3"
    cssClass="tdLabelwidht"  
    onchange="InsertSelect()"
    id="selectid" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function InsertSelect(){
    var v=document.getElementById('selectid').value;
    alert(v);
    document.forms['grille'].action='ahmed';
    document.forms['grille'].submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: You "call" a Struts 2 action from JS like anything else in JS, you make a request. That can be done via Ajax, setting the page URL, etc.

Comment: Adding a little javascript query to the select tag to submit the form. You could show what did you try?

Comment: for insert many record in DB i have many <s:select> from iterator  I try do this <s:select  label="Select test"  headerValue="---- Select -----" headerKey="-1"  name="sousEvalItem.SousItem_ID"   list="#{'1':'list1','2':'list2'}"
 listKey="3" cssClass="tdLabelwidht"  onchange="InsertSelect()"
id="selectid" />  <script type="text/javascript">function InsertSelect(){varv=document.getElementById('selectid').value;alert(v);document.forms['grille'].action='ahmed';document.forms['grille'].submit();} </script>this example it's work but when i use <s:select> of the iterator did't work

Comment: Revise your question to include more detail, don't post it in comments.

Comment: I have changed my question

Comment: The `id` attribute of your select tags is not unique.

Comment: how can i increment it?

Comment: If you use `onchange` attribute then you can pass value directly to your function. No need to call `getElementById`.