# how can i incrément attribute name of <s:select> iterator

Tags: jquery, hibernate, jsp, struts2

since three days I try to insert many record in DB , I m using `struts 2 and hibernate 3`.I have 3 tables:

```
1 Evaluationglobale (id_eval ,label)
2 SousEval(id_eval ,SousItem_ID),
3 SousItems(SousItem_ID,label)
```

my issue is how to insert many record in table SousEval when using the last insert `id_eval` in table Evaluationglobale
for more explain i want do somthing like that :

table   Evaluationglobale :

```
id_eval        label
----------------------------
1              evaluation 1
```

table   SousItems:

```
SousItem_ID   SousItem_Libelle
----------------------------
1              sousitem 1
2              sousitem 2
3              sousitem 3
4              sousitem 4
```

i want insert somthing like that in SousEval

```
id_eval     SousItem_ID
----------------------------
1              1
1              2
1              3
1              4
```

And I don't know how to recupere all `SousItem_ID` from iterator from this jsp : t think that i need to increment the `attribute name` of `<s:select>` but i donnot know how 
 this is my jsp :

```
<form action="saveOrupdateSousEval" method="post">
    -----------------some code ------
    <TABLE  class="EvalTable" >
      <s:iterator value="item"  status="userStatus">
         <s:select  label="%{Item_Libelle}"
            headerValue="---------------- Select ---------------"
            headerKey="-1" 
            name="%{sousEvalItem.SousItem_ID}"  
            list="sousitem"
            listKey="SousItem_ID"  
            listValue="SousItem_Libelle"
            cssClass="tdLabelwidht"
            value="%{#request.name}"  
         />
    </s:iterator>
    </TABLE>
    <s:texfield type=hidden value="%{id_eval}" name="id_eval" />       
</form>
```

My class SousEvaluationDao :

```
public void saveOrUpdateSousEval(List<SousEvaluation> sousevalnote) {
try {
    for (Iterator<SousEvaluation> it = sousevalnote.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
         session.saveOrUpdate(it.next());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    transaction.rollback();
    e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

in myclass action:

```
--------    
private List<SousEvaluation> sousevalnote=new ArrayList<SousEvaluation>();
private SousEvaluationDao sousevaldao=new SousEvaluationDaoImpl();
    ---
public String saveOrUpdateEval(){   
    sousevaldao.saveOrUpdateSousEvaluationNote(sousevalnote);
    return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call struts2 action from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469194/how-to-call-struts2-action-from-javascript)

Comment: Yes I have changed my question and put more information.I tray whit javascript now i think that i should know how to incrment attribute of tag <s:select> I'm stuck here i can't insert many record

Answer (score 0):

You can use hibernate by itself, If you trying to insert many values into table with data such as that.

Create a project and add all hibernate required jars. Since, I am not sure about DB type you are using, I could provide an example using derby database.

You need three files:
1) configuration file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/EventDB;create=true</property>
    <property name="connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="connection.password">123</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">2</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <!-- Names the Annotated Entity Class -->
    <mapping class="org.EventLogPrint.EventLog"/>


  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

2) Class for table you trying to insert values in:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity(name="Event_Log")
public class EventLog {

    @Id
    @Column (name ="Event_Id")
    private int event_id;

    @Column (name="Run_Id")
    private int run_id;

    @Column (name="Job_Name")
    private String job_name;

    public int getEvent_id() {
        return event_id;
    }
    public void setEvent_id(int event_id) {
        this.event_id = event_id;
    }

    public int getRun_id() {
        return run_id;
    }
    public void setRun_id(int run_id) {
        this.run_id = run_id;
    }
    public String getJob_name() {
        return job_name;
    }
    public void setJob_name(String job_name) {
        this.job_name = job_name;
    }

}
```

3) Class for inserting values:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class TestEventLog {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.configure();

        ServiceRegistryBuilder srb = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties());
        SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory(srb.buildServiceRegistry());

        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        for(int i = 1; i < 51; i++){            
            EventLog eventLog = new EventLog();
            eventLog.setEvent_id(100+i);
            eventLog.setJob_name("job name"+i);
            eventLog.setRun_id(1000+i);

            session.save(eventLog);
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

change for loop value based on how many objects you want to inser.

Not sure if this is the approach you would like to take, but thats the one way i know it.